# What could be the possible reason of buffer overflow in snprintf command in C?

Tags: printf, c-preprocessor, buffer-overflow, fortify

I have defined preprocessors and the code is structured as below. When I test my code using a code scanning software(fortify) it shows that there can be a potential buffer overflow error in snprintf() statement.

```
#define start_process(1.1)
    snprintf(struct->string, max_len, "%s", source_string) \\char string[max_len]={0} its a part of a structure..

#define start_process(1)
    start_process(1.1)

int process(){
    start_process(1)
    }
```

Comment: Is `max_len` a compile-time constant?

Comment: yes..it is a compile time constant

Comment: It looks like a false positive but its hard to know without seeing your code. It is possble that fortify wants you to check the return value to see if it is an error, although with a C99 implementation, that should not be necessary in this case. It is also possible that fortify has established that `struct->string` does not necessarily point at what you think it points at. As always, a [mcve] would help both you and anyone trying to answer.

Comment: Like most static analyzers, most of its reports are false positives?  I've yet to find a static analyzer with a false positive rate below 90%